# How do I make an input show up in a print statement in Python

Tags: python

```
def main():
    print "This program calculates the future value of a 10-year investment"

    principal = input("enter the initial principle: ")
    years = input("enter number of years you want to invest: ")
    apr = input("Enter the APR: ")

    for i in range(years):
        principal = principal * (1 + apr)

        print "The amount in" years "years is: " , years, principal

main()
```

i am getting an error here.  how do i get the final print statement to show the input value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `,` to separate the strings and values.(`,` automatically adds a space)

```
print "The amount in", years, "years is:", principal
```

but a better way is to use string formatting:

```
print "The amount in {0} years is: {1}".format(years, principal)
```

***or:***

```
print "The amount in {years} years is: {principal}".format(years=years, principal=principal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "The amount in" years "years is: " , years, principal
```

I assume, should be:

```
print "The amount in" + str(years) + "years is: " + str(principal)
```

Or:

```
print "The amount in %(years) is : %(principal)" % { 'years': years, 'principal': principal }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing commas around `years`.  I assume this is your problem, but you don't specify what error you're getting.

Comment: this works and is what i think book wanted me to do.  what does the str above stand for?

Comment: `str(years)` gives you the string representation of years.

Answer (score 0):

The output line should be written as follows:

```
print "The amount in " + str(years) + " years is: " + str(principal)
```

Comment: Yep that's the exact same answer I gave 6 minutes before you did.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you have is that you don't have commas around the word 'years'. Try this.
    def main():
        print "This program calculates the future value of a 10-year investment"

```
    principal = input("enter the initial principle: ")
    years = input("enter number of years you want to invest: ")
    apr = input("Enter the APR: ")

    for i in range(years):
        principal = principal * (1 + apr)

        print "The amount in",years,"years is:", principal
```

Hope this works:)